# Space not allowd Regular expression operations in python

Tags: python

My code:

```
import re

text='10c0 '
pattern=re.compile("\d{0,9}[adc]\d{0,9}")
if pattern.match(text):
    print('Match')
else:
    print('Not Match')
```

the output:

```
Match
```

But in fact. There is a space after 0 in `text='10c0 '`. It should print `Not Match`

How can I make the space not allowed in `pattern=re.compile("\d{0,9}[adc]\d{0,9}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `$` to the end of it which signifies an end of string:

```
\d{0,9}[adc]\d{0,9}$
```

Comment: @de_jayce welcome, if i helped please press the tick next to my answer, thanks